# Facing problem in dual boot of Ubuntu 14.04 with window 8.1 on my leptop of lenovo G500 BIOS based

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I buy a laptop of Lenovo G500(4GB ram, 500GB HDD and quick heal total security licence antivirus) of BIOS mode. I install window 8.1 crack version and i want to install Ubuntu as dual boot. I tried to install and i face a problem. Problem is when Ubuntu did not shows the partition that i made in window 8.1 instead of that in Ubuntu it shows that a whole 500 GB HDD is free as single partition. Ubuntu did not show window 8.1 os or any partition i made before.

Once i try to make partition in ubuntu from 500 GB then it remove my previous os and then also ubuntu did not installed properly.

Also when enver installation start my screen brightness automatically redused to 0.

please help me i need dual boot for programming. please help me

Comment: did you format the partition or just leave it as raw/unpartitioned space? Also did you try running the live cd first? sometimes the integrated video cards have specific driver support

Answer (score 0):

Try shrinking your Win partition down using `diskmgmt.msc` in windows and leave the space you want to install linux in unpartitioned/unformatted/raw/with no file system. Then try your install again - it should now recognize the unformatted space and ask if you want to install side by side or over the whole disk.

Comment: I tried what you said i did shrink using diskmgmt.msc and made it as unpartitioned/unformatted/raw/with no file system but still ubuntu did not show it even ubuntu did not show my 500 GB HDD type or anything else information regarginh my 500 GB HDD, it only show that a 500 GB free space.

Comment: please give me another solution